# call svn as a subprocess to check out source code and expect returns

Tags: svn, return-value

If I use python to write a script to call `svn` as a `subprocess` to checkout source code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("svn checkout file:///tmp/repos/test mine")
```

What is the return value of the success or failure of `svn-checkout subprocess`?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Python 2.7 spec](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html), calling `Popen.wait()` or `Popen.poll()` sets the `Popen.returncode` attribute. I guess you can try:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("svn checkout file:///tmp/repos/test mine")
p.wait() # this deadlocks the thread until process completion, so use with care

# There was an error
if p.returncode != 0:
   # ...
```

According to the spec:

> The child return code, set by poll() and wait() (and indirectly by communicate()). A None value indicates that the process hasn’t terminated yet. A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (Unix only).

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the docs about Subprocess ?

```
 returnCode = p.returncode
```

This will contain the return code of the svn call.

Comment: OK, maybe I did not write it clearly. I know there is p.returncode. but what I want to know is, what is the return value for the success or failure of svn checkout, if there is any.

Comment: the exact value, not the code or variable. e.g. 0 for success. -1 for failure.

Comment: 0 means success anything else means something has gone wrong.

Comment: Thank you khmarbaise, for your follow-up. is it possible to know the failure type. e.g. if it is the password error, network connection error or wrong url error. I am asking this because i am developing a GUI with python. so I need this error type to give interactive feedback to the user.

Comment: As far as i know not. But you can ask on the Subversion dev-list for this kind of information. If you developing in Python why don't you use the pyhton bindings than you have more control on the error handling for this.

Comment: Here you find an example for Python with Python binding: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.developer.usingapi.otherlangs.ex-2